# comparing sets to multiple sets within a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to compare a set to multiple sets with a for loop?  I am trying to see if there is match when comparing against multiple sets.
I want to create a function that will allow any number of sets to compare.

```
ex1 = {'a','b','c'}
ex2 = {'a','b','c','d'}
ex3 = {'a','b','c','d','e'}

list_of_sets = [ex1,ex2,ex3]

my_dict = {
    "person1": ['a','b','c'],
    "person2": ['a','b','c','d'],
    "person3": ['a','b','c','d','e'],
    "person4": ['a'],
    "person5": ['x','y','z']
}

# this currently works for comparing a hard coded set
output = {}
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    if set(v) == ex1 or set(v) == ex2 or set(v) == ex3:
        output[k] = True

# something like this doesn't work:
output2 = {}
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    if any(set(v).issubset(s) for s in list_of_sets):
        output2[k] = True
```

Comment: "compare" how, exactly?  equality?  subset?  superset?

Comment: What do you mean  by _this doesn't work_? Your `output2` is `{'person1': True, 'person2': True, 'person3': True, 'person4': True}`, what is correct.

Comment: @JohnGordon Trying to match the set in the list to X number of sets

Comment: If you want to "match", then why are you calling `.issubset()`?

Comment: Sorry this is my mistake

Answer (score 0):

The second iteration is not the exact same logic. You would need

```
any(set(v) == s for s in list_of_sets)
```

To make the lookup more efficient, you could use a `set` of `frozenset`. Unlike normal sets, frozen sets are hashable, so you can avoid a lot of redundant set creations and comparisons that are happening for each query:

```
sets = {frozenset(s) for s in (ex1, ex2, ex3)}
output = {k: frozenset(v) in sets for k, v in my_dict.items()}
print(output)
```

```
{'person1': True, 'person2': True, 'person3': True, 'person4': False, 'person5': False}
```